# Writing contents of form to a text file

Tags: file, jsp

I have written a code where I want to get the contents of the form and write the same to the textfile. The code doesn't write to the text file. What is the problem with the following code?

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function mySave()
{



  var fo=fopen("D:\\t.txt",3);

 if(fo!=-1)

{
 var q=document.getElementByName("qn").value;
 var a=document.getElementByName("A").value;
 var b=document.getElementByName("B").value;
 var c=document.getElementByName("C").value;
 var d=document.getElementByName("D").value;

 fwrite(fo,q);
 fclose(fo);
 }
else
 {
return false;
}

</script>

  <body>
 <form method="post" action="text.jsp" onSubmit="mySave()">
  <center>
 <table>
 <tr><td>
  Question :</td><td><input type="text" size="75" name="qn"/></td></tr><tr><td>
   Option A :</td><td><input type="text" size="20" name="A"/></td></tr><tr><td>
   Option B :</td><td><input type="text" size="20" name="B"/></td></tr><tr><td>
   Option C :</td><td><input type="text" size="20" name="C"/></td></tr><tr><td>
   Option D :</td><td><input type="text" size="20" name="D"/></td></tr><tr><td>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" /></td></tr>
 </table>
 </center>
 <form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Why are you importing the java.io package when you are not using it. You are using pure javascript and not java scripting. The only java code is the import.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write to files using Javascript due to security concerns. There are ways to do it in Internet explorer using ActiveX controls, but since that's non portable, I wouldn't recommend it. Then there's HTML5 offline caching, but it's also not what you really want.

Short version: you can't write a file directly to a client's hard disk. Either write it on your server if you need to, or offer that file as a download to your client.

And, as Koekiebox mentioned, you have only one line of Java in your code, and that's

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
```

The rest of it is Javascript and Javascript knows nothing about `java.io.*`.